# WebStorm and ESLint (cannot find module 'usr/lib/node_modules/semistandard/lib/cli,js')

Tags: webstorm, eslint, standardjs

I just installed StandardJS and realised I want semicolons. I stumbled upon Semistandard (which is "all the goodness of standard + semicolons"), however I'm having difficulty adding it as my code style to my IDE (RubyMine).

I installed semistandard globally using `npm install semistandard -g` and selected it as my ESLint package, the same way I did with standard, however when I press apply, the IDE complains with the error message:

"ESLint: Initialization error (ESLint). Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/semistandard/lib/cli.js".

Has anyone encountered this error message or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semistandard is not supported, please vote for [WEB-29114](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29114)